# Nested md-checkbox not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, material-design, angularjs-material

I have a list i.e.

Supplier[1], Supplier[2]...Supplier[n]
Each supplier have a list within i.e. Material [1,2,3,4,5.....50]

the problem I am facing is that, as soon as I select the value using this check box, it gets reflected for both the supplier. How I can distinguish between the selected values for multiple suppliers. I tried using ng-model but then I am not even able to select the value in checkbox.

Could you please help me out ?

```
<md-list>
    <label>Free Trade Agreement*</label>
    <md-list-item ng-repeat="Lists in MatList">
        <md-checkbox 
            ng-checked="Lists.checked"
            ng-click="toggle($index,MatList,supIndex)"
            ng-value="Lists.label">
        </md-checkbox>
        <span>{{Lists.label}}</span>
    </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

Comment: Please post the JSON for MatList, or even better, put this in a codepen.

Comment: Hi Mike, MatList is something like Material [1,2,3,4,5.....50]

Comment: Use `ng-model` and set the value from the controller. Don't use `ng-checked`.

Comment: I tried doing that but of no avail.

Comment: I have tried to use ng-model but now all the checkbox are getting selected.